# access controls in Form1 from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one control `textBox1` that sits in my main form `Form1`. I want to be able to change the `textBox1` text from another class `another_class`, but I can't do it. My `another_class` has a event `teacher` that I handle from `Form1` by doing the following

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    another_class myNew_another_class = new another_class();
    myNew_another_class.teacher(sender, e);
}
```

So I can't create the following in `another_class` because it will mess with my handler above and red tag it

```
public another_class (Form1 anytext_Form)
{
    this.anytext_Form = anytext_Form;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get what your problem is, what is messing with your handler and why?

Answer (score 1):

Correct the syntax by:

```
partial class Form1 {
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        another_class myNew_another_class=new another_class(this);
        myNew_another_class.teacher(sender, e);
    }
}

public partial class another_class {
    Form anytext_Form;

    public void teacher(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // do something
    }

    public another_class(Form anytext_Form) {
        this.anytext_Form=anytext_Form;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that really helped, I spent 6 hours on that shit.

Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

I think you should explain *what you actually what to do*, because your event management doesn't look good IMO. Maybe the event isn't useful, or maybe you could refactor it if you tell us what you want to achieve actually.

To answer the question in your title, controls in another form are **private members**, so you can't access them outside the scope of the parent form. What you can do is expose public method that'll do the job:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public void SetMyText(string text)
    {
        this.myTextbox.Text = text;
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        var frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.SetMyText("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
another_class myNew_another_class = new another_class();
```

to this:

```
another_class myNew_another_class = new another_class(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     another_class myNew_another_class = new another_class(this); //where this is Form1
     myNew_another_class.teacher(sender, e);
}
```

This then is the constructor for your "another_class" as you had it.

```
public another_class (Form1 anytext_Form)
{
         this.anytext_Form = anytext_Form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you state your question clearly. What is `teacher` method doing?

However, as mentioned by others, all control access modifier is **Private**, so you cannot just directly access it. You can try to change the access modifier in the property of the object, or create a property:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
    public String TextboxText {
        set { this.myTextbox.Text = value; }
        get { return this.myTextbox.Text; }
    }
}
```